# Yii2 Customize yii\bootstrap4\ActiveField::radioList option

Tags: html, yii2, radiobuttonlist

I'm using `yii\bootstrap4\ActiveField::radioList` and I'm trying to insert html tag inside the options of my `radioList`.

```
$list = [
    0 => '<strong>Option1</strong><br>
        lorem ipsum lorem ipsum',
    1 => '<strong>Option2</strong><br>
        lorem ipsum lorem ipsum',
    2 => '<strong>Option3</strong><br>
        lorem ipsum lorem ipsum,',
];

echo $form->field($model, 'field')->radioList($list)->label('Your choose?');
```

Is there a direct way to do it without create a template ?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the [`items`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml#activeRadioList()-detail) option which gives you the ease to customize the `radio` or `checkbox` inputs and `labels`.

Although it is not clear what layout you are trying to follow for the `radioList` but you can change it in the code below, i will focus on what you have mentioned i.e formatting the text labels for the radio-list inputs.

```
$list = [
    0 => '<strong>Option1</strong><br>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum',
    1 => '<strong>Option2</strong><br>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum',
    2 => '<strong>Option3</strong><br>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum,',
];

echo $form->field($model, 'field')
    ->radioList(
        $list,
        [
            'item' => function ($index, $label, $name, $checked, $value) {

                $html = '<label >';
                $html .= '<input type="radio" name="' . $name . '" value="' . $value . '" ' . $checked . '>';
                $html .= '<span>' . ucwords($label) . '</span>';
                $html .= '</label>';

                return $html;
            },
        ]
    )
    ->label('Your choose?');
```